# full specialization of method within templated class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

This topic might exist, but the way in which one names this specific problem is confusing.

I have the following code - the first third is meant to be in an hpp file, second third in an impl file and last bit in a cpp. If I remove the commented out piece of code, it fails to compile for reasons I cannot understand.

Why does the compiler not complain about the other specializations I have, or alternatively - why does it not determine that line 45 is where my code is?

The errors:

```
test.cpp:45:23: error: no function template matches function template specialization 'foo'
int const A<int,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
                  ^
test.cpp:58:5: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    A<int, int>::foo( test_int );
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:21:22: note: candidate function
    static int const foo(int const & rhs);
                 ^
test.cpp:45:23: note: candidate function
int const A<int,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
                  ^
2 errors generated.
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename X, typename Y>
struct A {
    static X const foo(Y const & rhs);
};

template <typename X>
struct A<X,int> {
    static X const foo(int const & rhs);
};

template <typename Y>
struct A<int, Y> {
    static int const foo(Y const & rhs);
};


template <>
struct A<int,int> {
    static int const foo(int const & rhs);
};


//----------------------------------------

template <typename X, typename Y>
X const A<X,Y>::foo(Y const & rhs) {
    X ret;
    return ret;
};

template <typename X>
X const A<X,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
    X ret;
    return ret;
};

template <typename Y>
int const A<int, Y>::foo(Y const & rhs) {
    return 42;
};

//If I uncomment the following line, the compiler barfs
//template <>
int const A<int,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
   return rhs;
};




int main() {
    std::string test_str;
    int test_int;
    A<int,std::string>::foo( test_str );
    A<std::string,int>::foo( test_int );
    A<std::string,std::string>::foo( test_str );
    A<int, int>::foo( test_int );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete specialization is not a template, but a class. When you type:

```
template <>
int const A<int,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
   return rhs;
};
```

The compiler sees that you want to specialize (`template <>`) a member function of a template `A` that takes two arguments. The member you are trying to specialize is for an specialization of the template where both arguments are `int`. The compiler tries to find the best match and cannot find it, since there are two equally good candidates: `A<X,int>` and `A<int,Y>` that could use that member function specialization. At that point it gives up.

Since what you want to provide is the definition of the member for `A<int,int>`, and that is a full specialization (no longer a template) you need to use the usual syntax: *return type::member(args)*:

```
int const A<int,int>::foo(int const & rhs) {
   return rhs;
};
```

Comment: Does this mean that, if there was only one partial specialization for the template, either A<X,int> or A<int,Y>, would template<> have worked? I tried commenting out one of the definitions, but didn't work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @sajas: It would not have failed that way... although it would most probably not have done what you wanted. For an object of type `A<int,int>` the compiler will pick the full specialization of the type before the partial specializations `A<int,T>` or `A<T,int>` (which ever you left), when you called `foo` on that object it would find the declaration in `A<int,int>` specialization, but no definition. The member specialization for `(int,int)` in the partial specialization would never be called.

Comment: @sajas: Your test seems to fail for precisely the same reason, which I would expect but I don't understand why the problem shows up in the first place. Still trying to wrap my head around david's answer

Comment: @stackmate: It might be easier if we use different names. Say that the base template is `A`, that `A<X,int>` is `A1`, `A<int,Y>` is `A2` and `A<int,int>` is `A3`. Now, A3 is a complete specialization and thus not a template, you don't use `template<>` to define members of a type, so `template<>` being present, it must be the specialization of a member of one of A1, A2 or A3. Which one is it? Well, it uses `A<int,int>` so it matches A2 with `X==int` and A3 with `Y==int`. Neither is more specialized than the other, and thus it fails.

Comment: So, If we didn't had A2, the code should have compiled,right? But it doesn't compile.

Comment: @sajas: Yes, my bad. This is a part of the language I seldomly use and my memory failed. There are parts of the answer that are correct som others are noe.